# Filtra Json Personalizado

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, filtro

Tengo el siguiente JSON

```
const Menu = [{
    icon: "home",
    text: "Inicio",
    url: {
        name: "home"
    },
    typeUrl: "exact"
},
{
    heading: "Operaciones"
},
{
    icon: "settings",
    "icon-alt": "settings",
    text: "Operación",
    model: true,
    children: [{
        icon: "add",
        text: "Cargar Pedidos",
        url: {
            name: "cargarpedidos"
        }
    },
    {
        icon: "playlist_add_check",
        text: "Aprobar Pedidos"
    },
    {
        icon: "content_copy",
        text: "Remitir Pedidos"
    }
    ]
},
{
    heading: "Informes"
},
{
    icon: "widgets",
    "icon-alt": "widgets",
    text: "Informe",
    model: false,
    children: [{
        icon: "view_module",
        text: "Usuarios"
    },
    {
        icon: "view_module",
        text: "Perfiles"
    },
    {
        icon: "view_module",
        text: "Permisos Perfiles"
    },
    {
        icon: "view_module",
        text: "Resetear Password"
    },
    {
        icon: "view_module",
        text: "Cambiar Password"
    }
    ]
},
{
    heading: "APSI"
},
{
    icon: "view_module",
    text: "Informes del APSI"
},
{
    heading: "Administaciones"
},
{
    icon: "extension",
    "icon-alt": "extension",
    text: "Administración",
    model: false,
    children: [{
        icon: "face",
        text: "Usuarios"
    },
    {
        icon: "assignment_ind",
        text: "Perfiles"
    },
    {
        icon: "settings",
        text: "Permisos Perfiles"
    },
    {
        icon: "cached",
        text: "Resetear Password"
    },
    {
        icon: "fingerprint",
        text: "Cambiar Password"
    }
    ]
},
{
    heading: "Mantenimientos"
},
{
    icon: "build",
    "icon-alt": "build",
    text: "Mantenimiento",
    model: true,
    children: [{
        icon: "group_work",
        text: "Departamentos"
    },
    {
        icon: "room",
        text: "Locales"
    },
    {
        icon: "donut_large",
        text: "Unidades de Medida"
    },
    {
        icon: "spellcheck",
        text: "Articulos"
    },
    {
        icon: "toc",
        text: "Categorías"
    },
    {
        icon: "supervisor_account",
        text: "Usuario Aprobador"
    }
    ]
}
];

export default Menu;
```

Lo utilizo para crear el menu de mi sistema que lo estoy desarrollando con VueJS + Vuetify y necesito filtrarlo por el campo "text" por palabras que la contengan sin importar la posición, al estilo like '%filtro%' de SQL, también sin distinguir mayúsculas y minúsculas. En lo posible que no distinga acentos (pero esto ya es muy fino, si no es posible o es muy engorroso, puedo omitirlo).

También en el caso que el patrón de coincidencia esté en un nodo hijo y no en el padre, este padre también tiene que aparecer en el filtro, es posible hacer esto con una función Javascript?

El menu se ve asi:

[image]

Y espero este resultado

[image]

Comment: El menú se vería de esta forma

https://fotos.subefotos.com/2657c73440e1064e2c17a7a8ad85e588o.png

Comment: ¿Algo como `let filtrado = Menu.filter(item => item.text.toLowerCase().includes(filtro.toLowerCase());` ?